# STM32 development - program "works" with Eclipse IDE but not with VScode

Tags: visual-studio-code, stm32

I do most of my embedded development with VScode and cortex-debug.  I've never really had an issue until recently. I have an STM32H745, which has multiple cores.  I wrote some code to the M7 and some code for the M4.  I am using two different workspaces and I noticed the M4 would not "run".  When debugging it would go into this section of code:(assembly)

```
/**
 * @brief  This is the code that gets called when the processor receives an
 *         unexpected interrupt.  This simply enters an infinite loop, preserving
 *         the system state for examination by a debugger.
 * @param  None
 * @retval None
*/
    .section  .text.Default_Handler,"ax",%progbits
Default_Handler:
Infinite_Loop:
  b  Infinite_Loop
  .size  Default_Handler, .-Default_Handler
```

Which I have never seen before. As you may be aware, multi-core debugging with cortex-debug is a bit tricky, so I try to avoid it.  But since I could not get this to work, I opened STM32CubeIDE and it worked fine.  So, through hours of troubleshooting I've determined it has something to do with the way I am building/linking.  I have some simple serial output upon boot and I can whether the code above has executed because the serial output will not complete.

To get this far I:

- Used OpenOCD to program both enviroment's ELF.   VScode fail, Eclipse success
- Used GCC from inside and outside the STM environment: VScode fail, Eclipse success

I can literally 'make' the program from Eclipse and program it. Works.
Same environment, 'make' my code and it won't work.

I've compared the build outputs both for GCC and the linker.  I've made my Makefile look like the one Eclipse generated.  But it still doesn't work.  I'm stumped.

**Eclipse generated output:**

*Assembly file:*

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-m4 -g3 -DDEBUG -c -x assembler-with-cpp -MMD -MP -MF"Core/Startup/startup_stm32h745zitx.d" -MT"Core/Startup/startup_stm32h745zitx.o" --specs=nano.specs -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -o "Core/Startup/startup_stm32h745zitx.o" "../Core/Startup/startup_stm32h745zitx.s"
```

*.C file*

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc "../Core/Src/usart.c" -mcpu=cortex-m4 -std=gnu11 -g3 -DDEBUG -DCORE_CM4 -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DSTM32H745xx -c -I../Core/Inc -I../../ -I../../Drivers/STM32H7xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -I../../Drivers/STM32H7xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -I../../Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32H7xx/Include -I../../Drivers/CMSIS/Include -O0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -fstack-usage -MMD -MP -MF"Core/Src/usart.d" -MT"Core/Src/usart.o" --specs=nano.specs -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -o "Core/Src/usart.o"
```

*Linker:*

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -o "STM32H745_Ethernet_CM4.elf" @"objects.list"   -mcpu=cortex-m4 -T"G:\My Drive\EE Projects\Electricity Monitor\stm32\STM32H745_Ethernet\CM4\STM32H745ZITX_FLASH.ld" --specs=nosys.specs -Wl,-Map="STM32H745_Ethernet_CM4.map" -Wl,--gc-sections -static --specs=nano.specs -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -Wl,--start-group -lc -lm -Wl,--end-group
c:/users/jagau/arm-gnu-toolchain-12.2.rel1-mingw-w64-i686-arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/12.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: warning: STM32H745_Ethernet_CM4.elf has a LOAD segment with RWX permissions
'Finished building target: STM32H745_Ethernet_CM4.elf'
```

**VSCode generated output:**

*Assembly file:*

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -x assembler-with-cpp -c -mcpu=cortex-m4 -std=gnu11  --specs=nano.specs  -mthumb -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -DDEBUG -DCORE_CM4 -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DSTM32H745xx -ICore/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32H7xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32H7xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32H7xx/Include -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Include -I.. -I "C:/Program Files (x86)/GNU Arm Embedded Toolchain/10 2021.10/arm-none-eabi/include" -O0 -g3 -Wall -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -fstack-usage -g3 -MMD -MP -MF"build/startup_stm32h745zitx.d" Core/Startup/startup_stm32h745zitx.s -o build/startup_stm32h745zitx.o
```

*.C file*

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -c -mcpu=cortex-m4 -std=gnu11  --specs=nano.specs  -mthumb -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -DDEBUG -DCORE_CM4 -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DSTM32H745xx -ICore/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32H7xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -I../Drivers/STM32H7xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32H7xx/Include -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Include -I.. -I "C:/Program Files (x86)/GNU Arm Embedded Toolchain/10 2021.10/arm-none-eabi/include" -O0 -g3 -Wall -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -fstack-usage -g3 -MMD -MP -MF"build/usart.d" Core/Src/usart.c -o build/usart.o
```

*Linker:*

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc build/main.o build/app_main.o build/gpio.o build/usart.o build/utils.o build/sysmem.o build/syscalls.o build/ringbuff.o build/system_stm32h7xx_dualcore_boot_cm4_cm7.o build/stm32h7xx_hal_cortex.o build/stm32h7xx_hal_rcc.o build/stm32h7xx_hal_rcc_ex.o build/stm32h7xx_hal_flash.o build/stm32h7xx_hal_flash_ex.o build/stm32h7xx_hal_gpio.o build/stm32h7xx_hal_hsem.o build/stm32h7xx_hal_dma.o build/stm32h7xx_hal_dma_ex.o build/stm32h7xx_hal_mdma.o build/stm32h7xx_hal_pwr.o build/stm32h7xx_hal_pwr_ex.o build/stm32h7xx_hal.o build/stm32h7xx_hal_i2c.o build/stm32h7xx_hal_i2c_ex.o build/stm32h7xx_hal_exti.o build/stm32h7xx_hal_tim.o build/stm32h7xx_hal_tim_ex.o build/stm32h7xx_hal_uart.o build/stm32h7xx_hal_uart_ex.o build/startup_stm32h745zitx.o -mcpu=cortex-m4 -std=gnu11  --specs=nano.specs  -mthumb -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -specs=nosys.specs -static -TSTM32H745ZITX_FLASH.ld  -lc -lm  -Wl,-Map=build/EEMon_CM4.map -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--start-group -Wl,--end-group -o build/EEMon_CM4.elf
c:/users/jagau/arm-gnu-toolchain-12.2.rel1-mingw-w64-i686-arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/12.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: warning: build/EEMon_CM4.elf has a LOAD segment with RWX permissions
```

As I stated, I am stumped as to what is happening.  Why this works in Eclipse and not VSCode when using the same build tools, same linker script, etc.

I'd appreciate any pointers.

Comment: The default handler is typically called when a fault happens. Frequently due to invalid adress due to bad flash programmation, buffer overflow, etc...

Comment: You should separate the compilation, the programmation and the debug.

Comment: The compilation and link command lines should be strictly identical: did you write a makefile or did you use an existing build system from the IDEs ?

Comment: I have decoupled the process to the point I know it's related to the build.   As far as I can tell the linking is identical, but I can take another look.  This Makefile was "edited" by me, but generated from a different project.  I think I am going to adapt the eclipse Makefile into my project and see if that just "fixes" it.

Comment: did you have a look to the .map files to check that the code and data are placed in the same memory areas ?